# Prolog - List into String

Tags: string, list, prolog

im done of searching here for a solution but nothing so i decided to ask.

So, i have a query that returns in a list something like this:

```
List = [6-"read",3-"magazines",3-"music",1-"sport"].
```

And i need to perform a transformation so do i can get the list like this:

```
List = [read,magazines,music,sport]. 
or 
List = ["read","magazines","music","sport"].
```

For that i think i should pass first the to a string to take out the numbers and the '-'. But im struggling with that.

Hope someone can help me! Thanks

Comment: Define `pair_string(_N-S, S).` and then do `PairStringList = [6-"read",3-"magazines",3-"music",1-"sport"], maplist(pair_string, PairStringList, StringList).`

Comment: if you're using SWI-Prolog, beware to difference in string implementation WRT ISO Prolog

Comment: Using [library(yall)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall), `maplist([_-S,A]>>atom_string(A,S), List, Result).`

Answer (score 3):

This looks like homework, so I will not give you the full implementation. What you are looking for is pattern matching in a rule head:

```
fst_pair(X, pair(X,Y)).
```

The `-` operator is just an infix function symbol such that you could write

```
fst(X, X-Y).
```

Using this kind of pattern matching it should be easy to write a recursive predicate over the list. It must have a base case for the empty list and a step case for a head followed by the tail of the list:

```
fsts_list([], []).
fsts_list([ ... | TailFirsts ], [... | Pairs] ) :- % replace ... by some terms
   % possibly insert some predicates here, depending on what you do above
   fst_lists(TailFirsts, Pairs).
```

Happy solving!